# Undeclared identifier error for only select methods

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, erc-721, openzeppelin

I have a contract that inherits from ERC721. I'm trying to use some methods from the parent contract in the child contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "../../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "../../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract MyContract is ERC721 {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter public _tokenIds;
    constructor() ERC721("My Token", "TOKEN") {

    }

    // ERC720 token transfer
    function tokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) public {
        require(_isApprovedOrOwner(msg.sender, tokenId), "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved");
        _transfer(from, to, tokenId); // this works
    }

    // Set up an operator
    function setOperator(address operator, bool approved) public {
        require(tx.origin != operator, "ERC721: approve to caller");
        _setApprovalForAll(tx.origin, operator, approved); // doesn't work
    } 
}
```

But, I'm getting the following error for `_setApprovalForAll`:

> Undeclared identifier. Did you mean "setApprovalForAll"?

The `tokenTransfer` method is just an arbitrary example that's identical to `transferFrom` to prove a point. How am I able to use [_transfer](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/52d42d6e03ba7940b78a4940ce13bca70aa4dacc/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L327) and not [_setApprovalForAll](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/52d42d6e03ba7940b78a4940ce13bca70aa4dacc/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L362) here even though they are both `internal` methods?

I've tried importing all the contracts and interfaces that the ERC721 protocol requires to see if it makes any difference, but still got the same result:

```
import "../../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";
import "../../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Receiver.sol";
import "../../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/IERC721Metadata.sol";
import "../../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol";
import "../../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol";
import "../../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
import "../../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection/ERC165.sol";
```

Comment: Not the answer but never use tx.origin…. Too dangerous

Comment: Which version of openZeppelin are u using?

Comment: @MajdTL I'm using OpenZeppelin Contracts v4.3.2

Comment: @MajdTL can you explain the dangers of using `tx.origin`? I've been trying to find a way to use `msg.sender` instead, but the problem is I'm using this contract as similar to a library where the methods are called by another contract as such `myContract.tokenTransfer`. In this case, the `msg.sender` is always this second contract, not the actual owner of the token.

Comment: Then **maybe** add additionally(msg.sender == the second contract or == operator) to **try** to limit the risk. Without it the operator could be tricked to call a contract (like call to get ether) and then that contract could forward the call and trigger your method with any parameter it want to add new/change operator because the tx.origin is the original operator

Answer (score 0):

Your code, of course has no problems. Here is the same code, with URL substituted, compiling successfully in Remix

[image]

You have a package version problem. Please delete the `node_modules` folder and reinstall.